# The Tag Synonyms page is a bit repetitive

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

The [Tag Synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) has a tab called "Pending approval Pending approval [sic]".

[image: screen shot]

The source for this control is as follows:

```html
<a href="?tab=Newest&amp;filter=Active" class="s-btn s-btn__muted active-filter float-right" title="Only active tag synonyms">
    <span class="s-btn--text" data-text="Active">Active</span>
</a>
<a href="?tab=Newest&amp;filter=Suggested" class="s-btn s-btn__muted active-filter is-selected float-right" title="Only suggested tag synonyms (excluding voted synonyms)">
    <span class="s-btn--text" data-text="Pending approval">Pending approval</span>
    <span class="-status">Pending approval</span>
</a>
```

Apparently the line `<span class="-status">Pending approval</span>` should not be there.

---

Additionally, the "Pending merge" button available to moderators is similarly duplicated

```html
<a href="?tab=Newest&amp;filter=Merge" class="s-btn s-btn__muted active-filter is-selected float-right" title="Active synonyms requiring a merge">
    <span class="s-btn--text" data-text="Pending merge">Pending merge</span>
    <span class="-status">Pending merge</span>
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Same with [pending merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP2Ie.png), though that might be mod-only